# Too Many Promises in single nodejs route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await, transactions, query-optimization

I want to know if one of the promises fail how can i rollback or cancel already happened operations.

and 2nd is there any other way to optimize code, it takes more time to resolve.

As the number of joined player will increase it will be taking more time is there any way to optimise it more

```
route.put("/UpdateResult/:id", Get_User_id, async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const response = await tournamentschema.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        {
          Game_Name: req.body.Game_Name,
          Total_Players: req.body.Total_Players,
          Prize_Pool: req.body.Prize_Pool,
          Joined_User: req.body.Joined_User,
          Is_Finished: true,
        },
        { new: true, runValidators: true }
      );
      response.Joined_User.forEach(async (Player) => {
        await UserModal.findByIdAndUpdate(
          Player.UserId,
          {
            $inc: {
              Wallet_Coins: Player.Kills * parseInt(response.Prize_Pool),
            },
          },
          { new: true }
        );
      });
      return res.send("Result Updated Sucessfully");
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

for optimize :
in ES7 and 8 we are have new feature called promise all in for your problem its better you don't use forEach for your await function its better in first you get all your id in new array like this :

```
let playerCacheId = []
response.Joined_User.forEach((Player) => { 
playerCacheId.push(player.id)
}
await Promise.all(playerCacheId .map(playerId => UserModal.findByIdAndUpdate(
          playerId ,
          {
            $inc: {
              Wallet_Coins: Player.Kills * parseInt(response.Prize_Pool),
            },
          },
          { new: true }
        );
      });
 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

To rollback Operations use MongoDB Transactions